# How can I use NSDateFormatter to generate 2012-07-28T23:59:00-06:00?

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

What is the appropriate way to format this string:

2012-07-28T23:59:00-06:00

This is the code I am using and the date formatter is currently setting the value of s.due_At to nil and both NSLogs are displaying null. I am getting the string above back from the dictionary for sure I have NSLogged it.

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
                [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
                s.due_At = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[assignmentData  objectForKey:@"due_at"]];


                NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:s.due_At]);
                NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter dateFromString:[assignmentData objectForKey:@"due_at"]]);
```

How can I fix this to output the above string?

Comment: Are you certain that `[assignmentData objectForKey:@"due_at"]` is not returning nil?

Comment: What is your device time setting? 24h or am/pm? I had the same issue and it hat something to do with the time format and unfortunately I was not able to fix it. Did you try to comment out the row with setLocale?

Comment: Yes I am absolutely certain [assignmentData  objectForKey:@"due_at"] is returning a string. I can create a string object locally and nslog the value. Furthermore if I send the locally created string to  NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter dateFromString:localString]) I still get null. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes I did commit out set locale to no avail still did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Z` literal means RFC 822 standard which does not allow you to have `:` between hours and minutes:

```
 zone        =  "UT"  / "GMT"                ; Universal Time
                                             ; North American : UT
             /  "EST" / "EDT"                ;  Eastern:  - 5/ - 4
             /  "CST" / "CDT"                ;  Central:  - 6/ - 5
             /  "MST" / "MDT"                ;  Mountain: - 7/ - 6
             /  "PST" / "PDT"                ;  Pacific:  - 8/ - 7
             /  1ALPHA                       ; Military: Z = UT;
                                             ;  A:-1; (J not used)
                                             ;  M:-12; N:+1; Y:+12
             / ( ("+" / "-") 4DIGIT )    ; Local differential
                                             ;  hours+min. (HHMM)
```

Comment: Is their another literal I can use or do I have to strip the time zone from the string? I would prefer to keep it. Thanks

Comment: @xitzxmythicx there're only two literals: `z` and `Z`, neither is compatible with your timezone format. In general to sanitize the string you need to analyze the six of final string characters, if `:` is met you try to find `GMT` in the complete string because `:` is allowed to use like `GMT+3:00`, if there's `:` in the end but no `GMT` in the complete string, you remove this `:` and the string is ready to be parsed.

Comment: I am very sorry I am not sure what your saying. From my interpretation just remove the : in the last part/timezone part of the string and leave this line alone [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];. Or just specify GMT+. Please If you would provide me with an example.

Comment: @xitzxmythicx unfortunately i do not have objC example to share, your understanding is correct: if you are confident the timestamps format will never change you can simply remove the last `:` or insert `GMT` two characters before it. I've tried to describe the general solution that will allow you to use the same code to parse also the correct timestamps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Ok so I changed the code a bit. Here it is

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. Ok so I changed the formatter a bit. Here is the code.

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
            [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmssZ"];


            s.due_At = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[[assignmentData objectForKey:@"due_at"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""]];

            NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:s.due_At]);
```

The Nslog is no longer null although it still contains the T in the middle. 
This is the log message now.

2012-07-29T015900-0400

Comment: How do I get rid of the T. What am I doing so wrong here. Thanks

Comment: To change the formatted date style, use `setDateStyle` and `setTimeStyle` as described at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: @A-Live Thanks for the help everything is working as expected.